# CanActivate is giving error after switching to r.c.3

Tags: angular

I am using CanActivate in my angular2 app like this

`@CanActivate(() => isValidUser())`

It was working fine until i switched to r.c.3 and it started giving me error.

Please suggest me the recent changes regarding this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an auth.guard.ts in the app folder:

app/auth.guard.ts:

```
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then in your routes.ts:

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: YourComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```

If you don't have routes.ts, you need to create one, see the reference here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html